# What exception to throw if a bad constructed tree is detected?

Tags: java, tree

On a tree class I wrote I detect if the tree was constructed in such a way that there is a closed path from a node to itself (in which case it is a graph more than a tree)

What kind of exception is advised to throw in such cases?

Comment: IllegalStateException would be my best bet if I understand you correctly

Comment: @PontusBacklund You said what i thought :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the exception is due to a wrong parameter passed to a specific method, `IllegalArgumentException`.

If it is due to a series of operations that bring the tree to an invalid state: `IllegalStateException`.